# How to read a text file by line in python

Tags: python, text, random, indexing, line-by-line

I want to randomly retrieve and print a whole line from a text file.

The text file is basically a list and so each item on that list needs to be searched.

```
import random

a= random.random

prefix = ["CYBER-", "up-", "down-", "joy-"]

suprafix = ["with", "in", "by", "who", "thus", "what"]

suffix = ["boy", "girl", "bread", "hippy", "box", "christ"]

print (random.choice(prefix), random.choice(suprafix), random.choice(prefix), random.choice(suffix))
```

this is my code for if i were to just manually input it into a list but i can't seem to find how to use an array or index to capture line by line the text and use that

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to randomly choose one of those three lists? Do you want to choose a random element from each list?

Comment: what do you mean by `The text file is basically a list `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're asking, but I'll try to help.

- If you're trying to choose a random line from a file, you can use [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open), then [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines), then [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice):

  ```
  import random
  line = random.choice(open("file").readlines())
  ```
- If you're trying to choose a random element from each of three lists, you can use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice):

  ```
  import random
  choices=[random.choice(i) for i in lists]
  ```

  `lists` is a list of lists to choose from here.

Comment: That helped completely. the first section works perfectly. 

If i wanted to search 2 lists then how does the second section work?

Comment: @FrancisBrady `lists` is a list of lists to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python's **file.readLines()** method:

```
with open("file_name.txt") as f:
    prefix = f.readlines()
```

Now you should be able to iterate through the list `prefix`.

Answer (score 0):

Those answers have helped me grab things from a list in a text file. as you can see in my code below. But I have three lists as text files and I am trying to generate a 4 word message randomly, choosing from the 'prefix' and 'suprafix' list for the first 3 words and 'suffix' file for the fourth word but I want to prevent it, when printing them, from picking a word that was already chosen by the random.choice function

```js
import random

a= random.random

prefix = open('prefix.txt','r').readlines()

suprafix = open('suprafix.txt','r').readlines()

suffix = open('suffix.txt','r').readlines()

print (random.choice(prefix + suprafix), random.choice(prefix + suprafix), random.choice(prefix + suprafix), random.choice(suffix))
```

as you can see it chooses randomly from those 2 lists for 3 words